# os.symlink and window's .lnk files are different

Tags: python-3.x

I am processing a big images dataset and I'm trying to reorder the files in classes, while at the same time keeping the original directory structure.
To do this, I make a second directory structure with symlinks to the files in the first one.

Everything works as it should but for one small detail: the symlinks created via `os.symlink()` do not show the image thumbnail, while if I make a link of the same file (e.g., via right click & send to Desktop) I do see the thumbnail.

I wanted to check how the two link files differ (note, the link files themselves, not the linked file), but if I try to drag the `os.symlink`-generated file in a text editor it opens the linked file instead (while this does not happen with the `.lnk` file generated via right-click).

What's the difference between the link files? Is `os.symlink` making something different than a `.lnk` file? If so, is there a way to get the thumbnail? And if there's no such way, how can I make a `.lnk` file instead?

Comment: A .lnk file is a binary file that defines a Windows shell shortcut. `os.symlink` is nothing like that. It calls `CreateSymbolicLink` to create a file-system reparse point. In the kernel, when the file-system driver is parsing a path and reaches a reparse point such as a symbolic link with a fully-qualified target, it has the system reparse the target path starting from the top.

Comment: The shell knows whether a file is a reparse point, and it seems to be conservative about generating thumbnails in this case. Maybe there's a setting to enable it. If not and thumbnails are a requirement, then you'll have to create .lnk shortcuts instead. It's relatively easy if you have PyWin32 installed.

Comment: I see! I thought os.symlink would just use a OS-specific way of creating links but I didn't know windows had two ways of linking things. You should rework your comments into an answer, so that I can flag it as resolving my question. Thanks!